# Update-Database for multiple projects, with only one context?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a solution with two projects:

- `MyProject.Database`
- `MyProject.Database.Test`.

Both projects contain an `app.config`, where a the `connectionstring` is specified as such:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="TrackerDB" 
   connectionString="Host=hostName; user id=userName; 
                     password=myPassword; database=TrackerDB" providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="TrackerDB" 
   connectionString="Host=hostName; user id=userName; 
                     password=myPassword; database=TrackerTestDB" providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

(Notice the difference at the `database` attribute).

With this setup all my tests will run its own database, with generated data, and a database for the real data runs separately.

Whenever I do a `Update-Database` I set the project with the `DbContext` (`MyProject.Database`), but this will not update `MyProject.Database.Test` database.

What should I do to automatically update both databases?

Comment: have you tried using `DbContext.Save()`?

Comment: @JamesJoyceAlano Will that generate a scheme for my second database? That is what i am missing.

Comment: Transactional Replication between the databases perhaps.

Comment: I'd write a wrapper for the context that simply took both contexts and sets the entries in both of them. Can't think of any other solution using solely EF.